# How to conditionally disable a join in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle, specifically.   I need to do the following in SQL in a declarative query, without defining a variable or if condition.  Consider the following SQL:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 on table2.a = table1.a
    WHERE table1.d = 4 
    AND c = (select c from table3 where b=3);
```

The catch is, if there is NOT a match in table3, then instead of table3 limiting the rows , the table3 condition should not apply (effectly just removing the last line of the above query)

How can I do that in a single SQL statement without defining a variable first?

Comment: in which table is the column c contained - table1 or table2

Comment: I don't get your logic.  It seems to me that the restriction doesn't even need to be there at all.  Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `NOT EXISTS` clause to effectively remove the `c = ...` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
JOIN table2 on table2.a = table1.a
WHERE table1.d = 4 
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT c FROM table3 WHERE b=3)
       OR c = (SELECT c FROM table3 WHERE b=3)
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

The subquery returns at most one value.  Here are two ways that you can handle this without an additional subquery:

```
c = all (select t3.c from table3 t3 where t3.b = 3)
```

This works because `all` matches to an empty list.

```
c = (select coalesce(max(t3.c), ?.c) from table3 t3 where t3.b = 3)
```

The `?` is for the outer table reference.  This works because `max()` will return `null` if there are no matches.  The `coalesce()` then replaces the value with a matching value.  Note:  This assumes that the outer `c` is not `null`.

Comment: An anonymous downvote on a correct answer is quite curious.

Answer (score -2):

You would want to consider using left join on the table that contains the col c, as follows

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM table1
     JOIN table2 
       on table2.a = table1.a
LEFT JOIN (select distinct c 
             from table3 
            where b=3
           )tbl_3
       ON table1.c=tbl_3.c /*i assumed that the column c is in table1*/
    WHERE table1.d = 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't accomplish the goal